# format diff php (%h+%i)/60

Tags: php, diff

I want to be able to convert a result like this. '4.5'

The following code I get this result `04.30`  if I look for the difference between two hours

```
$first_time  = '16:30:00';
$last_time   = '12:00:00';

$dif_min       = new DateTime($first_time);
$dif_max       = new DateTime($last_time);
$result        = $dif_min->diff($dif_max)
$result_end    = $result->format('%H.%i'); 

echo $result_end /*04.30*/
/* I would like this 4.5 */
```

I hope I explain well

Comment: `$result_end = $result->h + $result->i / 60;`

Comment: @Nick dude why always give a positive number?

Comment: You need to take account of the `invert` flag: `$result_end = ($result->h + $result->i / 60) * ($result->invert ? -1 : 1);`